# Undefined error in scope

Tags: javascript, if-statement, global-variables

Why does I get undefined error in my console with this code:

```
var fromDateData;

if(!util.isEmpty(formItem.fromDate)){
        fromDateData = util.tmpl('{year}-{month}-{day}',{      
        day: ("0" + formItem.fromDate.getDate()).slice(-2),
        month: ("0" + (formItem.fromDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        year: formItem.fromDate.getFullYear( )
    }); 
}

  console.log("customData", fromDateData);
```

but if I remove the `if statement` then it will work:

```
var fromDateData;


        fromDateData = util.tmpl('{year}-{month}-{day}',{      
        day: ("0" + formItem.fromDate.getDate()).slice(-2),
        month: ("0" + (formItem.fromDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        year: formItem.fromDate.getFullYear( )
    }); 


  console.log("customData", fromDateData);
```

I need to use the `if statement`. What did I missed because I already declared `fromDateData` as global variable. So it should work outside of the statement right? Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `util`? Where does it come from?

Comment: why space in brackets () `year: formItem.fromDate.getFullYear(  )` ?
try type console.log inside if, your console.log 'gets' from var fromDateData not from fromDateData inside `if` thus `undefined`

Comment: @Grisza Spaces are permitted between them and won't affect the meaning.

Comment: `fromDateData` isn't being given a value when the `if` condition is `false` – when `formItem.fromDate` is actually empty. It starts as `undefined` since that's the default value for variables, it isn't being altered in that case, so you get `undefined`. – Either give it an initial value or also assign it within an `else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error since the the value of ( formItem.fromDate ) is undefined when your trying to access it. You need to add one more check in your if condition like below and make sure your fromDate has some values to validate. Hope this will solve the issue.

```
var fromDateData;

    if( formItem.fromDate != 'undefined' &&  !util.isEmpty(formItem.fromDate)){
            fromDateData = util.tmpl('{year}-{month}-{day}',{      
            day: ("0" + formItem.fromDate.getDate()).slice(-2),
            month: ("0" + (formItem.fromDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
            year: formItem.fromDate.getFullYear( )
        }); 
    }

      console.log("customData", fromDateData);
```